# How can I update a text box 'live' in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to ask how would I go about maybe creating a 'LIVE' text box in python? This program is a simulator for a vending machine (code below). I want there to be a text box showing a live credit update How do you do that in tkinter?

For Example: Say there is a box for credit with 0 inside it in the middle of the window. When the `10p` button is pressed the box for credit should change from '0' to '0.10'.
Is it possible to do thit in tkinter and python 3.3.2?
Thank you in advance!

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk

credit = 0
choice = 0

credit1 = 0
coins = 0
prices = [200,150,160,50,90]
item = 0
i = 0
temp=0
n=0
choice1 = 0
choice2 = 0

credit1 = 0
coins = 0
prices = [200,150,160,50,90]
item = 0
i = 0
temp=0
n=0
choice1 = 0
choice2 = 0

def addTENp():
    global credit
    credit+=0.10

def addTWENTYp():
    global credit
    credit+=0.20

def addFIFTYp():
    global credit
    credit+=0.50

def addPOUND():
    global credit
    credit+=1.00

def insert():
    insert = Tk()

    insert.geometry("480x360")
    iLabel = Label(insert, text="Enter coins.[Press Buttons]").grid(row=1, column=1)

    tenbutton = Button(insert, text="10p", command = addTENp).grid(row=2, column=1)
    twentybutton = Button(insert, text="20p", command = addTWENTYp).grid(row=3, column=1)
    fiftybutton = Button(insert, text="50p", command = addFIFTYp).grid(row=4, column=1)
    poundbutton = Button(insert, text="£1", command = addPOUND).grid(row=5, column=1)


insert()
```

Comment: can't you just keep a reference to your coin amount label and change it's value text?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure you can! Just add another label to the frame, and update the `text` attribute whenever one of your add functions is called. Also, you can simplify that code, using one `add` function for all the different amounts.

```
def main():
    frame = Tk()
    frame.geometry("480x360")

    Label(frame, text="Enter coins.[Press Buttons]").grid(row=1, column=1)
    display = Label(frame, text="") # we need this Label as a variable!
    display.grid(row=2, column=1)

    def add(amount):
        global credit
        credit += amount
        display.configure(text="%.2f" % credit)

    Button(frame, text="10p", command=lambda: add(.1)).grid(row=3, column=1)
    Button(frame, text="20p", command=lambda: add(.2)).grid(row=4, column=1)
    Button(frame, text="50p", command=lambda: add(.5)).grid(row=5, column=1)
    Button(frame, text="P1",  command=lambda: add(1.)).grid(row=6, column=1)
    frame.mainloop()

main()
```

Some more points:

- note that you define many of your variables twice
- you should not give a variable the same name as a function, as this will shadow the function
- probably just a copy paste error, but you forgot to call `mainloop` and your `tkinter` import is inconsistent with the way you use the classes (without `tk` prefix)
- you can do the layout right after creating the GUI elements, but note that in this case not the GUI element will be bound to the variable, but the result of the layouting function, which is `None`

Comment: Thank you very much! @tobias_k Also thank you for the extra points! I will adjust my code according to that!

Comment: using an `IntVar` is probably better!

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing a framework from tobias_k's excellent answer, I would recommend you use a `DoubleVar` instead.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

def main():
    frame = Tk()
    frame.geometry("480x360")

    credit = tk.DoubleVar(frame, value=0)
    # credit = tk.StringVar(frame, value="0")

    ttk.Label(frame, textvariable = credit).pack()

    def add_credit(amt):
        global credit
        credit.set(credit.get() + amt)
        # new_credit = str(int(credit.get().replace(".",""))+amt)
        # credit.set(new_credit[:-2]+"."+new_credit[-2:])

    ttk.Button(frame, text="10p", command = lambda: add_credit(0.1)).pack()
    # ttk.Button(frame, text="10p", command = lambda: add_credit(10)).pack()

    ttk.Button(frame, text="20p", command = lambda: add_credit(0.2)).pack()
    # ttk.Button(frame, text="20p", command = lambda: add_credit(20)).pack()

    ttk.Button(frame, text="50p", command = lambda: add_credit(0.5)).pack()
    # ttk.Button(frame, text="50p", command = lambda: add_credit(50)).pack()

    ttk.Button(frame, text="P1",  command = lambda: add_credit(1.0)).pack()
    # ttk.Button(frame, text="P1",  command = lambda: add_credit(100)).pack()

    frame.mainloop()
```

The comments in that code is an alternate implementation that will work better, if only just. This will guarantee you won't have any strange floating-point errors in your code.

Comment: +1 I was just editing this into my answer. ;-) However, I would use a `StringVar` (and a separate numeric variable for the actual amount), otherwise the label will show funny stuff like `0.3000...4`

Comment: @tobias_k I wish there was a way to format a `textvariable`, since the BEST answer is to use an `IntVar` to hold the raw value in pence (e.g. 1 pound is now `100` instead of `1.0`) then format the `Label` to show it correctly.

Comment: @tobias_k I hacked it together in comments, take a look.